# AppleScript UI-scripting - conditional

Tags: applescript

I want to click a radio-button in System Preferences if another radio-button is selected, like this:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click menu item "Mouse" of menu "View" of menu bar 1

if radio button "Right" is selected <-- pseudo-code
    tell window "Mouse"
        tell radio group 1
            click radio button "Left"
        end tell
    end tell
end if

if radio button "Left" is selected <-- pseudo-code
    tell window "Mouse"
        tell radio group 1
            click radio button "Right"
        end tell
    end tell
end if

end tell
end tell
```

anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will revert the primary button to "Left" if it is currently set to "Right":

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell radio group "Primary mouse button:" of window "Mouse"
            if value of radio button "Right" is 1 then
                click radio button "Left"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Setting the primary button to "Right" will confuse the hell out of most users.

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Just needed to plug in an else-statement to get it to work.

You're right most users will fret if their primary button is set to "Right" - however due to a shoulder-injury I constantly change hands when using my trackball.